# webapp2 http error 500

Tags: python, html

I try to run a code snippet in goold app engine and find a weird problem. When I run the code snippet below, it report error:

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500

```
import webapp2
import cgi

form="""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>Unit 2 Rot 13</title>
  </head>    
  <body>
    <h2>Enter some text to ROT13:</h2>
    <form method="post">
      <textarea name="text" style="height: 100px; width: 400px;">{{text}}</textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Query">
    </form>   
</body></html>"""

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)
    def post(self):
        text = self.request.get('text')
        self.response.out.write(self.request)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

But when I delete one line code in my `post` method, it works well. The deleted part:`text = self.request.get('text')`
Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Other than an indentation error on the first line (which would present as a different problem), I don't see anything wrong with your code, and it works fine when running with `paste.httpserver`. Are you sure that you have posted the same code that is causing the problem?

Comment: @mhawke Yeah, it is the same code. Is paste.httpserver similar to Google App Engine?

Comment: `paste.httpserver` allows you to run your `webapp2` app [outside of app engine.](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/quickstart.nogae.html#quick-start-to-use-webapp2-outside-of-app-engine) You could try your code outside of app engine. Also, look at the app logs - a 500 error will usually be the result of an unhandled exception in your code, or a failure to run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the space from first line.

Then display the "text" which you get from the user.

```
text = self.request.get('text')
self.response.out.write(text)
```